# Bounded Measurable Functions on [0,1]^2

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Suppose $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ are two functions on $[0,1]^2$ that are bounded and measurable, such that:
$$ \int_0^1 f(x,u)g(y,u) du \leq 1 $$
for almost every $(x,y) \in [0,1]^2$. Show that
$$\int_0^1 f(x,u)g(x,u) du \leq 1 $$
holds for almost every $x \in [0,1]$.

Apparently there is a way to solve this question using martingales instead of conventional real analysis. But after trying for several hours I cannot seem to pick up on this question. If I can have some kind of general idea or hint to help me on the right track it would be most appreciated.

Comment: try proving $f(x)g(y)\leq 1\Rightarrow f(x)g(x)\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis for fixed x we have

$\int_{B_{r}(x)}\int_{0}^{1}f(x,u)g(y,u)dudy\leq \int_{B_{r}(x)}1dy=|B_{r}(x)|\Rightarrow $

$\int_{B_{r}(x)} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x,u)}{|B_{r}(x)|}g(y,u)dudy\leq 1$

Thus, by Fubini

$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x,u)}{|B_{r}(x)|}\int_{B_{r}(x)}g(y,u)dudy\leq 1$

Then by DCT and Lebesgue differentiation theorem we get

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x,u)lim_{r\to 0}\frac{}{|B_{r}(x)|}\int_{B_{r}(x)}g(y,u)dydu\leq 1\Rightarrow$

$\int_{0}^{1}f(x,u) g(x,u)du\leq 1.$

However, I think the assumption should be bounded a.e., because then we can't apply DCT and so Martingale analysis is needed.

Comment: Yes I believe that works. There should be a way to use Martingales however, but at the moment I view this question purely as a real analysis question.